# Trying to run function every quarter-second per element, why won't my count increment?

Tags: jquery

On document ready I have a function which is called (below), but it only ever increments once then loops infinitely thereafter, what did I do to cause this?

```
var initNavTransition = function (ELs, n, c) {
    console.log("n: "+n+ ". c: "+c+ ". ELs.length: "+ ELs.length);
    if (typeof variable === 'undefined' || !variable)
        c = 0;
    if (c < ELs.length) {
        if(c > 0)
            ELs[c-1].className = ELs[n-1].className.replace('hover', '');
        ELs[c].className += 'hover';
        c++;
        console.log('increment c: '+c);
        setTimeout(function() {
            initNavTransition(ELs, n, c);
        }, 250);
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    var navELs = document.querySelectorAll('nav li');
    initNavTransition(navELs, navELs.length);
    });
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What is `variable`?  If it is undefined of false you are constantly setting `c` back to 0.

Comment: I must say that with generic variables named `c`, `n` and `Els` and zero comments, the intent/purpose of your code is entirely unclear.  Meaningful variables names will allow other people to more easily understand your code.

Comment: My friend u made a small mistake. just change this thing .           if (typeof c === 'undefined' || !c)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you don't properly pass or initialize `c`.

Perhaps this:

```
if (typeof variable === 'undefined' || !variable)
```

should be this (which covers both cases and refers to `c`):

```
if (!c)
```

---

Or, perhaps even better, you can just pass `c` as `0` when you first call the function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var navELs = document.querySelectorAll('nav li');
    initNavTransition(navELs, navELs.length, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are not calling initNavTransition with c defined; but your check for variable should be a check on c instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/7xwMr/1/

```
var initNavTransition = function (ELs, n, c) {
    console.log("n: "+n+ ". c: "+c+ ". ELs.length: "+ ELs.length);
    if (!c)
        c = 0;
    if (c < ELs.length) {
        if(c > 0)
            ELs[c-1].className = ELs[n-1].className.replace('hover', '');
        ELs[c].className += 'hover';
        c++;
        console.log('increment c: '+c);
        setTimeout(function() {
            initNavTransition(ELs, n, c);
        }, 250);
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    var navELs = document.querySelectorAll('nav li');
    initNavTransition(navELs, navELs.length);
    });
```